# Is there any problem with using a dehumidifier in the bathroom?

Tags: bathroom, humidity

The window in our small bathroom has been blocked off with foam because it carried sound from neighboring kitchens to our bathroom (and sounds from our bathroom to their kitchen).  Obviously humidity is becoming an issue after this, with the potential for mold accumulation etc.  Would it be safe and effective to use a dehumidifier to solve this problem?  Most of the moisture comes from hot showers.

Comment: Yes, it would be mandatory. Code requires either a working window or an exhaust fan, *for this very reason*.  I think most reasonable AHJs would accept a dehumidifier in lieu, at least so long as the tenant has the option to open the window if they really want to (coz, that smell).  **This humidity will damage your house - take it seriously**. Landlords can come after you for all the damage.

Comment: Also you really ought to take a chunk of that foam and give it a flame and smoke test.  I.E. see how readily it burns. Time and time again (Sunshine Mine, Grenfell Towers, Browns Ferry Nuclear Plant, scary that last one)... people pretend the foam isn't flammable.  Worse, it emits a toxic smoke that incapacitates, so people pass out halfway to the exit door.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica How do you know it's mandatory?  I don't live in the US, Canada, or Western Europe.  A lot of assumptions there.

Comment: well that would be giving away my secrets :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I have one that I use often.

Works well, I have it on a timer so it switches on ready for my morning shower, it then sits on auto and turns off when the humidity is low enough.

I have to remember to empty the reservoir though.

Comment: Try looking at Sound-Insulated-Fans. I used this for a search term; "sound proof fan" If it works no pan of water to dump!

Comment: @Gil no, am actually looking at a through wall fan with heat recovery and humidity control.